# Replace items in a list -- in place

Tags: c#, list, enumerator

I'm facing an issue with some simple C# code which I would easily fix in C/C++. 
I guess I'm missing something.

I want to do the following (modifying items in a list -- in place):

```
//pseudocode
void modify<T>(List<T> a) {
  foreach(var item in a) {
    if(condition(item)) {
      item = somethingElse;
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that foreach loops on a collection viewed as immutable, so the code above can't work.

I therefore tried the following :

```
void modify<T>(List<T> a) {
  using (var sequenceEnum = a.GetEnumerator())
  {
    while (sequenceEnum.MoveNext())
    {
      var m = sequenceEnum.Current;
      if(condition(m)) {
         sequenceEnum.Current = somethingElse;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Naively thinking that Enumerator was some kind of pointer to my Element. Apparently enumerators are also immutable.

In C++ I would write something like that:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node {
    T* value;
    Node* next;
}
```

being then able to modify `*value` without touching anything in `Node` and therefore in the parent collection:

```
Node<T>* current = a->head;
while(current != nullptr) {
    if(condition(current->value)) 
        current->value = ...
    }
    current = current->next;
}
```

Do I really have to to unsafe code?

Or am i stuck the awfulness of calling subscript inside the loop?

Comment: "Either C# has serious issues" - do you realize how many people use C#? Do you really think if there were serious issues with the language it would be one of the most popular out there? Take a step back and think about it. The problem is far more likely to be you than the language.

Comment: ok I remove my humour from my question

Comment: What's wrong with using a `for` loop?

Comment: and C since I added templates

Comment: So what would be the effect of `condition` evaluating true? That item in the list gets set null?

Comment: @Jamiec : that item is modifed. I took default to simplify the code

Comment: (properties) modified & set default(null in the case of reference types) is a *very* different thing. Ask the right question and you'll get an accurate answer.

Comment: @KennethK. I don't know. Won't it call subscript at each iteration, yielding terrible performances?

Comment: All you have to do is switch to a for loop instead of foreach. The same thing you'd have to do it in C++ since it doesn't have foreach. You're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Why would indexing a list yield terrible performance? Are you writing code for the Mars rover?

Comment: @itsme86 C++11 does have a range-based `for`, which is the equivalent of c# `foreach`

Comment: @Jamiec: the item is completely replaced by another value

Comment: @RegisPortalez. As far as I know a for loop performs about as good, if not better than a foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7), `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` is a generic implementation of the `System.Collections.ArrayList` which has O(1) complexity in indexed accessor. Very much like C++ `std::vector<>`, complexity of insertion/addition of elements is unpredictible, but access is time constant (complexity-wise, with respect to caching, etc).

The equivalent of your C++ code snippet would be [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

As for the immutability of your collection during iteration, it is clearly stated in the documentation of `GetEnumerator` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1). Indeed, during enumeration (within a `foreach`, or using `IEnumerator.MoveNext` directly):

> Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they
>   cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.

Moreover, modifying the list will invalidate the enumerator and usually throw an exception:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

I believe this interface contract consistency between various types of collections leads to your misunderstanding: it would possible to implement a mutable list, but it is not required by the interfaces contract.

Imagine you want to implement a list that is mutable during enumeration. Would the enumerator hold a reference to (or a way to retrieve) the entry or the entry itself ? The entry itself would make it unmutable, a reference would be invalid when inserting elements in a linked list for example.

The simple for loop proposed by @Igor seems to be the best way to go if you want to use the standard Collections library. Otherwise, you may need to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Having an explanation on why subscript is OK on List is what I expected. I naively thought that List was the c# implementation of std::list, where add is free but [] has a O(n) complexity. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a simple `for` loop.

```
void modify<T>(List<T> a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (condition(a[i]))
        {
            a[i] = default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In short - do not modify lists. You can achieve desired effect with

```
a = a.Select(x => <some logic> ? x : default(T)).ToList()
```

In general lists in C# are immutable during iteration. You can hovewer use .RemoveAll or similar methods.

Comment: I explicitely asked to do my modification in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
List<T> GetModified<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, bool> condition, Func<T> replacement)
{
   return list.Select(m => if (condition(m)) 
                        { return m; }
                       else
                        { return replacement(); }).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
originalList = GetModified(originalList, i => i.IsAwesome(), null);
```

But this can also get you into trouble with cross-thread operations. Try to use immutable instances where possible, especially with IEnumerable.

If you really really want to modify the instance of list:

```
//if you ever want to also remove items, this is magic (why I iterate backwards)
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (condition)
   {
     list[i] = whateverYouWant;
   }
}
```

Comment: That is correct, you get a new version of the list. Ah wait, I will update my answer a bit.